# Non Decreasing Number Combinations (Interval)

Tags: functional-programming, numbers, combinations, intervals

So my problem is the following:

Given a number X of size and an A (1st number), B(Last number) interval, I have to find the number of all different kind of non decreasing combinations (increasing or null combinations) that I can build.

Example:

```
Input: "2 9 11"

X = 2 | A = 9 | B = 11
```

Output: `8`

Possible Combinations ->

```
[9],[9,9],[9,10],[9,11],[10,10],[10,11],[11,11],[10],[11].
```

Now, If it was the same input, but with a different X, line X = 4, this would change a lot...

```
[9],[9,9],[9,9,9],[9,9,9,9],[9,9,9,10],[9,9,9,11],[9,9,10,10]...
```

Comment: Don't you miss [10] in the first example?

Comment: Yeah, I did miss it :/ sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be reformulated to simplify to just two parameters
X and N = B - A + 1 to give you sequences starting with 0 instead of A.

If you wanted exactly X numbers in each item, it is simple **combination with repetition** and the equation for that would be

```
x_of_n = (N + X - 1)! / ((N - 1)! * X!)
```

so for your first example it would be

```
X = 2
N = 11 - 9 + 1 = 3
x_of_n = 4! / (2! * 2!) = 4*3*2 / 2*2 = 6
```

to this you need to add the same with `X = 1` to get `x_of_n = 3`, so you get the required total `9`.

I am not aware of simple equation for the required output, but when you expand all the equations to one sum, there is a nice recursive sequence, where you compute next (N,X) from (N,X-1) and sum all the elements:

```
S[0] = N
S[1] = S[0] * (N + 1) / 2
S[2] = S[1] * (N + 2) / 3
...
S[X-1] = S[X-2] * (N + X - 1) / X
```

so for the second example you give we have

```
X = 4, N = 3
S[0] = 3
S[1] = 3 * 4 / 2 = 6
S[2] = 6 * 5 / 3 = 10
S[3] = 10 * 6 / 4 = 15
output = sum(S) = 3 + 6 + 10 + 15 = 34
```

so you can try the code here:

```js
function count(x, a, b) {
  var i,
    n = b - a + 1,
    s = 1,
    total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < x; i += 1) {
    s *= (n + i) / (i + 1); // beware rounding!
    total += s;
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(count(2, 9, 11)); // 9
console.log(count(4, 9, 11)); // 34
```

**Update**: If you use a language with `int` types (JS has only `double`),
you need to use `s = s * (n + i) / (i + 1)` instead of `*=` operator to avoid temporary fractional number and subsequent rounding problems.

**Update 2**: For a more functional version, you can use a recursive definition

```
function count(x, n) {
    return n < 1 || x < 1 ? 0 : 1 + count(n - 1, x) + count(n, x - 1);
}
```

where `n = b - a + 1`

Comment: I tried that way you made, and it makes sence, but it didnt work.
On [2,9,11] it gave me 12.But why dont u do the factorial of both elements and divide them just like you didon the 1st example? why did you came up with this other solution?

Comment: Not sure why would that give you 12, because if you run the code in a browser (with JS console open) you will see the result is really 9 and 34, so it really works. Also there is just one solution I presented, the first is just not reusing the already computed part with lower Xs, so it is much more computation - no factorials.

Comment: There is a problem, at the input "2 4 5" :S check it mate...
It should give "5" and gives "4".

Comment: I dont understand why this doesnt work...
[C++]

`int comb(int x,int a,int b)

{

    int i;

 int s = 1;

 int n = b - a + 1;

 int total = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < x; i+= 1)

 {

  s *= (n + i) / (i + 1);

  total += s;

 }

 return total;

}`

Comment: updated the answer... there is int truncation involved when C++ int used.

Comment: yeah I've already fixed it mate! Thanks.
It is needed, on C++, when dividing, do it like "1.0f". If we don't, it will round the number to a lower one, so it was giving 4.5, but it rounded to 4... With the modification, it is corret! Thanks.